# docker: command not found if called in a cronjob

Tags: docker, unix, cron

On my server (QNAP) I can run docker:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.11-qnap6, build 90a753c
```

If I want to run the same docker command in a crontab

```
$ sudo crontab -e
* * * * * docker -v >> /root/cron.log
```

I do get the error log

```
/bin/bash: docker: command not found
```

I do not understand why docker cannot be used as a crontab job, but it works, if I run it directly.

Comment: You must set up the PATH environment variable, or call docker with its full pathname.

Comment: enter as sudo and share the result of `docker ps`

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica How do I get the full path of docker?

Comment: @JRichardsz I already called `crontab -e` with sudo

Comment: To get the full path run "which docker"

Comment: yes but there is a problem with your docker when root user is used. Just open another shell, enter as root with `sudo su` and execute `docker ps`. Also the same with a simple user. Compare the results and add them to your question

Comment: @JRichardsz `sudo: su: command not found`

Comment: What exact os are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first run:

```
whereis docker
```

Mine is:

```
/usr/bin/docker
```

Then modify crontab file as below:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/docker -v >> /root/cron.log
```

You also can change crontab file like this (above your crontab commands):

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The complete sample in your case:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * docker -v >> /root/cron.log
```